Dual X, dual Y, and Z steppers motor control using marlin firmware
I am trying to make a 3d coater in which I want to have dual X, dual Y, and a Z axis control. This will require the control of 5 stepper motors using 5 stepper drivers. I have controlled the 2 Y-axis (clones of each other) using Y and E1 slots on the Ramps1.4 after modifications in configuration.h, configuration_adv.h, and pin_ramps.h files of Marlin firmware. But a similar procedure is not working for the dual clone X-axis in which I am using two slots, X and E0, due to the compilation error.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to control both X and E0 simultaneously.
Thank you.

welcome [tour] [ask] [mre] [help/on-topic] [help/dont-ask]
